# How to load page and scroll to html element via url link?

Tags: html

I the front page of my site I have this link: http://temporal-16.d246.dinaserver.com/serveis#formulario

Also tried with http://temporal-16.d246.dinaserver.com/serveis/#formulario

And then in the destination page I have this:

```
<h2 style="text-align: center;" id="formulario"><a href="#formulario"></a>Sol·licita el teu servei aquí</h2>
```

Problem is that the page load but not in the correct place to show the h2 element first.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please reform you question... as it is unclear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to HTML 4 the destination had to be

```
<a name="formulario">Sol·licita el teu servei aquí</a>
```

<sub>(note the name without the #)</sub>

but with HTML 5, this is obsolete and replaced by `id`

```
<h2 id="formulario">Sol·licita el teu servei aquí</h2>
```

see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

> This [name] attribute was required for anchors defining a possible target location within a page. In HTML 4.01, id and name could be used simultaneously on a `<a>` element as long as they have identical values.